# Group nested arrays by first element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contains individual 2-elements arrays, each contains a date in milliseconds in the first cell and a number (transaction number) in the 2nd cell. It looks like this:

```
var array = [[12135435123, -2],
[12135435123, 1], 
[12135464565, -2], 
[12423675834, 0], 
[12423675834, 1]....];
```

Not all the dates in ms are the same in every cell and I completely made up the dates above, but the logic is the same.

What I want to do is create another array in the same structure as above (2-elements arrays inside a global array). Each element in the global array is a 2-element array that represents a group of arrays that has the same date, as follows: `[transactionsCount, netTransaction]`.

`transactionsCount` is the count of unique date instances, or the number of transactions there are in a unique date.
`netTransaction` is the sum of the second cells in this group, or the value of the net transactions for a date.

Using the above example, I want the final array to look like this:

```
var newArray = [[2, -1], [1,-2],[2,1]...];
// The first array is 2 and -1 because there are 2 transactions for the unique day and the -1 is the net transaction amount. The 2nd array is 1,-2 because there is only 1 transaction for the day with a net total of -2, etc, etc.
```

What I did was create a primitive function that does this for me, but I have issues because there are instances where the function overcounts the number of the unique days and gives out wrong results. So there is something I am doing wrong here. Here is what I have:

```
transactions = function transactions(array){
  var transactionCount = 0;
  var netTransactionCounter = 0;
  var finishedArray = [];
  var tempDateArray = [];

  array.forEach(function(item){
    var init = [];
    if(tempDateArray.length == 0){
      tempDateArray.push(item[0]);
      transactionCount++;
      netTransactionCounter += Number(item[1]);
    } else if(tempDateArray.length > 0){
      if(item[0] == tempDateArray[0]){
        transactionCount++;
        netTransactionCounter += Number(item[1]);
      } else if(item[0] !== tempDateArray[0]){
        tempDateArray.pop();
        tempDateArray.push(item[0]);
        init.push(transactionCount);
        init.push(netTransactionCounter);
        finishedArray.push(init);
        transactionCount = 1;
        netTransactionCounter = Number(item[1]);
      }
    }
  });

  return finishedArray;

}
```

I really don't like using `forEach`, but I did in this case because it's less messy. If anyone can help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a hard time figuring out your logic, especially with that undefined `testing` array.

I would use a dictionary logic to collect the dates as unique keys. Plus it saves the effort to manage the lengths computing (with all the counters you have defined).

I would say the following code is pretty self explainetory, but if you have a problem understanding it, don't hasitate to ask.

```
var array = [[12135435123, -2],
[12135435123, 1], 
[12135464565, -2], 
[12423675834, 0], 
[12423675834, 1]];

function transform (array) {
 var dictionary = {};
 for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
   var date = array[i][0].toString();
   var value = array[i][1];

   // add the date to the dictionary if it's not already there
   if ((date in dictionary) === false)
     dictionary[date] = [0, 0];
   // update the count
   dictionary[date][0]++;
   // update the net sum
   dictionary[date][1] += value;      
 }

 // transform dictionary values to array
 var result = [];
 for (var key in dictionary) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(dictionary, key)) {
        var val = dictionary[key];
        result.push(val);
    }
 }
 return result;
}

alert(transform(array));
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fue5nr6r/).

Comment: Sorry about the testing part. I forgot to change it because I changed the variables before posting on here to make more sense when asking the question. Thanks for your answer. I'll get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Your method is much more aesthetic and works smoother than what I did above. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

This uses es6 for convenience but can easily be converted to es5:

```
var array = [[12135435123, -2],
[12135435123, 1], 
[12135464565, -2], 
[12423675834, 0], 
[12423675834, 1]];

//reduce the array into a map, creating objects using the date as keys - with the value being a hash of count and amount;

var map = array.reduce((map, [date, amount]) => {
  if (map[date]) {
    map[date].count = map[date].count + 1;
    map[date].amount = map[date].amount + amount;
  } else {
    map[date] = { count: 1, amount }
  }
  return map;
}, {});

//Map over keys returning tuples of count and amount
var newArray = Object.keys(map).map(key => [map[key].count, map[key].amount]) //gives the result you want;
```

If you want to get leaner and use more destructuring you can change up the reduce a bit as well:

```
//reduce the array into a map, creating objects using the date as keys - with the value being a hash of count and amount;

var map = array.reduce((map, [date, amount]) => {
  var { count, net } = (map[date] || { count: 0, net : 0 });
  map[date] = { count: count + 1, net: net + amount };
  return map;
}, {});

//Map over keys returning tuples of count and amount
var newArray = Object.keys(map).map(key => [map[key].count, map[key].net]) //gives the result you want;
```